# Openssl is unable to establish SSL connection, when I try to access a local site through third party tools like wget

Tags: windows-10, wget, openssl, monitoring

I want to monitor the index of a site periodically on our local network out of browsers. I tried to download it by `wget` in *Windows10*:

`> wget --no-check-certificate --no-hsts --content-on-error --ignore-length --unlink --server-response --show-progress --verbose https://172.*.*.*:*/app`

But it couldn't fetch the page. Here is the result:

```
--2019-02-02 16:56:01--  https://172.*.*.*:*/app
Connecting to 172.*.*.*:*... connected.
OpenSSL: error:2406F079:random number generator:RAND_load_file:Cannot open file
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I also tried with other tools like [urlwatch](https://thp.io/2008/urlwatch) and curl. None of them were able to get access to that page! Is there any idea? Here is the error given by urlwatch:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='172.*.*.*', port=*):
Max retries exceeded with url: /app
(Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1,
'[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

Comment: It looks like your clients are trying to negotiate SSL version 3. This is an old protocol, and most webservers have disabled support for it in preference to TLS 1.0/1.1/1.2/1.3
Can you use `openssl` and its s_client connect functionality to check that you can successfully negotiate a SSL connection to that system? Try `openssl s_client -connect 172.*.*.*:<port>`

Comment: Check the file `openssl.cnf` for a `RANDFILE=...` configuration line and remove if found. Or are you using PowerShell where `wget` is an alias for [Invoke-WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)? If you aren't, then you should consider using it.

Comment: @ssnobody: 'sslv3 alert handshake failure' only means the alert code (40) was first defined by sslv3; it does not mean sslv3 protocol was tried (or used). Although we can't be sure 'urlwatch' is using the same OpenSSL 'wget' is, the 'wget' is definitely using 1.1.1, and post-POODLE versions of OpenSSL (1.1.0 and 1.1.1) don't even _compile_ sslv3 capability by default. That said, I concur with trying `s_client` if possible, and although a host accessed by address _probably_ isn't using SNI, if < 1.1.1 consider adding `-servername $host` -- mini: browser _can_ access this server _by address_?

Comment: @harrymc: some commandline utilities use RANDFILE from configfile, but libssl does not. The error message shown from 'wget' is definitely OpenSSL (used by real wget) not MS schannel (used indirectly by powershell). Although it might be a wget version not updated for OpenSSL 1.1.1, which returns error from RAND_load_file in (quite a few) cases where prior versions ignored the error and just returned 'no data', which is usually ignorable since RAND still autoseeds.

Comment: There is no reason in Windows 10 to use a third-party tool to download a file when this is built into PowerShell. You may use [Invoke-WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6) or [Client.DownloadFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2). Let me know if you wish me to post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Why You don't try curl instead ?

For your reference go to [this](http://www.compciv.org/recipes/cli/downloading-with-curl/) site

It is [very common](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/07/wget-curl) to replace wget with curl under some scenarios. Probably this case is a good one to go with curl instead.

You can check this short [example](https://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/use-curl-on-windows-10/) with Windows 10

If the problem persist, definitely You will require to update ssl to the latest version or use Open SSL library for Windows 10. To avoid risk installing third party installer, get further details from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50625283/how-to-install-openssl-in-windows-10).

The Git for Windows installation already contains the openssl.exe You need, You can get it from [here](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/install-git#windows). I have used this solution in the past and worked well.

Check this for your [reference](https://serverfault.com/questions/889631/curl-fails-to-retrieve-https-content-error14094410ssl-routinesssl3-read-byte) as well.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason in Windows to use a third-party tool to download a file,
when such tools already exist natively,
especially if that tool is badly adapted to Windows.

For downloading a file, you may use PowerShell with the methods of
[Invoke-WebRequest](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-webrequest?view=powershell-6)
or
[Client.DownloadFile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfile?view=netframework-4.7.2),
and here are some examples:

```
    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://download.sysinternals.com/files/Handle.zip' -OutFile C:\handle.zip
    download.file("https://download.sysinternals.com/files/Handle.zip",destfile="C:\handle.zip")
```

Comment: Here is how you might call it from outside of powershell (so you can use it just like wget) --> "powershell.exe -Command (new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://download.sysinternals.com/files/Handle.zip','c:\my_out_dir\Handle.zip')" <--